# How to redirect unauthorized users to another page?

Tags: cakephp

I have implemented gone through:

- [Simple Acl controlled Application](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html)
- [Simple Acl controlled Application - part 2](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/part-two.html)

How can I set a message or redirect to another page if a user is unauthorized?

Comment: Read [Checking Permissions: The ACL Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html#checking-permissions-the-acl-component)

Answer (score 0):

I cakephp 3.4 below

Simply check if logged in or type of user

```
$user = $this->Auth-user();
```

In cakephp 3.5 above using Authentication Component

```
$result = $this->Authentication->getResult();

// Check the user
$user = $result->getData();

if (!$result->isValid()) {
    // Do your redirect here
    $this->redirect(['controller' => 'controllerName', 'action' => 'actionName']);
}
```

But if I were you I would have created a Layout for errors or redirections or access denied.